# UWP SerialDevice Reading Arduino

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port

I try to reading lines that sent from Arduino Uno using USB connection.
My program on Arduino working fine and I get data from Arduino in my universal app.

In the serial monitor from Arduino IDE can I see that the data is correct sent.

This shows like:

```
22.77;29.35;101352.00
22.77;29.36;101340.00
22.77;29.35;101347.00
22.77;29.35;101348.00
```

This is my code for Arduino:

```
void loop() {
  float temp = htu.readTemperature();
  float humidity = htu.readHumidity();
  float pressure = bmp.readPressure();

  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(humidity);
  Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(pressure);
  Serial.print("\r\n");
}
```

In the visual studio output window:

```
2201365.00
22.68;29.
35;101360.00
5;10136
```

This is my code in C#:

```
private async Task RetrieveData()
{
    string filter = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM7");
    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(filter);

    if (devices.Any())
    {
        string deviceId = devices.First().Id;
        _device = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

        if (this._device != null)
        {
            this._device.BaudRate = 9600;
            this._device.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            this._device.DataBits = 8;
            this._device.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            this._device.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

            _dataReader = new DataReader(_device.InputStream);

            while (true)
            {
                var bytesRecieved = await this._dataReader.LoadAsync(21);
                if (bytesRecieved > 0)
                {
                    string data = _dataReader.ReadString(bytesRecieved);
                    string[] block = data.Split('\n');

                    Debug.WriteLine(data);

                    //await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    //{
                    //    _tblkTemperature.Text = block[0].Split('=')[1] + " °C";
                    //    _tblkHumidity.Text = block[1].Split('=')[1] + "% rH";
                    //    _tblkPressure.Text = block[2].Split('=')[1] + " Pa";
                    //});
                }

                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have search a solution for a long time but I found nothing.

Comment: check if the baud rate matches with that of the arduino. And try removing the delay, also you can try checking by reading synchronously

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have configured the baudrate to 9600 and i remove the Task.Delay() from my "while" loop but the problem is still exist.

Comment: From the look of it the line length is 23 characters long - 21 characters in the data, then carriage return/newline - so use LoadAsync(23). Also change DebugWriteLine to Debug.Write - that way you are not displaying an additional CRLF and artificially modifying your data.

Comment: as @PaulF suggested try changing LoadAsync parameter to different values such as 22,23,24,25,26 and check the output, the problem is reading asynchronously. To avoid this, set up a delay in arduino before sending each data. That way you can set LoadAsync to a higher value and wait for the next message with delay.

Comment: I would also use a terminal emulator application (like PuTTY) just to check what is actually being received.

Comment: Thank you PaulF for your answer. Now i see that is correct displayed in the output window but when i check the variable "data" then i see the string "2323.10;30.35;101323". Any idea?

Comment: It does look like data may be missing for some reason - possibly stop bits or parity not being correct. This is why I suggest using a terminal application - you can easily change all of the setup parameters like that & see what is being received - once you are confident the correct data is being received, then you can concentrate on debugging the application.

Comment: @PaulF i have added a delay before sending data. this show like this   delay(100);
  Serial.println(temp + String(";"));
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(humidity + String(";"));
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(pressure + String(";"));

But the problem is still exist :-(

Comment: @PaulF I have checked the serial port settings. StopBits and Parity all over the same. In putty i see that the output correct displayed such as visual studio output windows but in the variable not.

Comment: It looks like your code relies on it being perfectly synchronised with the Arduino - you are always reading data in 23 character blocks. If the method is called while a line of data is being sent you will always be getting the end of one line & the start of the next. You could add a ReadTimeout shorter than your delay & if bytesReceived is not 23 (or whatever your line length is) then read & discard that data - hopefully you should be back in sync the next time. Alternatively, modify you code to read a byte at a time & build the data up in a buffer - stopping at CRLF.

Comment: everything what i tried that didn't work. how i can read byte?

Comment: [DataReader.ReadByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readbyte#Windows_Storage_Streams_DataReader_ReadByte)

Comment: @PaulF thank you for your help. This proposal helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution…
I read the stream byte to byte and convert this to char. If i see a CRLF then is my string completed and the task returns the line.

```
                string line = await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    int next_char;
                    String data = "";
                    while (true)
                    {
                        await _dataReader.LoadAsync(1);
                        next_char = _dataReader.ReadByte();
                        if (next_char == '\n') { break; }
                        if (next_char == '\r') { continue; }
                        data += Convert.ToChar(next_char);
                    }
                    return data;
                });
```

Many thanks four the support. :-)